# The following graph has 45 vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

From Hunter, *Essentials of Discrete Mathematics* (2012), exercise 2.6, question 20(c).

[image: 45-vertex graph]

The graph below is a copy of the above graph, but with some additional edges added so that all of the vertices in the resulting graph have degree four.

[image: 45-vertex graph with added edges]

How many edges does this new graph have? Explain how you can use a theorem from this section to make counting the edges easier.

Comment: The sum of degrees is 4 * BLANK = BLANK so the number of edges is BLANK by theorem 2.6

Comment: Hint: every vertex has degree 4, so each vertex "owns" half each of 4 different edges.

Comment: Note that this is also a product graph, so maybe your textbook would prefer that you use this fact instead of my hint.

Comment: @malia "Theorem 2.6" doesn't mean much to those of us without the book, but probably it is the Handshaking Lemma (see JavaMan's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The [Handshaking Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) gives the precise relation between the number of edges in a graph and the sum of the degree of the vertices of a graph.  If you know the degree of each vertex, then, you know the sum of the degrees in the graph, and hence the number of edges.